# How can I move an image with the mouse in pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, mouse

How do I write code such that the image is controlled by mouse movement in Python using pygame?

I have already tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame
import random

pygame.init() 
size=[800,600] 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sub Dice")

background_position=[0,0]
background_image=pygame.image.load('C:\Users\SHIVANGI\Desktop\shivangi project\program\star.png').convert()
card=pygame.image.load('C:\Users\SHIVANGI\Desktop\shivangi project\program\lappy.png').convert_alpha()
card=pygame.transform.smoothscale(card,(130,182))
closeDeckShirt=pygame.image.load('C:\Users\SHIVANGI\Desktop\shivangi project\program\star.png').convert_alpha()

SETFPS=30
zx=0
zy=0

done=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while done==False:
    clock.tick(SETFPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('a')


        screen.blit(background_image, background_position)
        screen.blit(card,[zx,zy])
        zx=zx+2
        zy=zy+2
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit ()
```

However, the motion is restricted only to one direction irrespective of where I move the mouse. I want the image to move forward and to have sideways motion controlled by the motion of the mouse.

Also, my aim is to create a game like wings over water available at orisinal.

Comment: One thing unrelated to Pygame - your file paths inside strings should use double `\`s  or use the forward slash (`/`)  otherwise they will probably be broken - as `\` is a scape char inside Python strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close to making this work.
I've made a few small edits.

So, your program has 2 problems. The first is that your program is moving the image on EVERY `pygame.event` regardless of the event -- you'll see this by hitting a key, clicking the mouse etc. The second problem is that you're moving the image in a fixed direction.

The only thing that I changed was your `while` loop:

```
while done==False:
    clock.tick(SETFPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('a')
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION: # We only want to move the image when the mouse is moved.
            mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # Where is the mouse at?
            screen.blit(background_image, background_position)
            screen.blit(card, [zx, zy])
            zx = mouse_position[0] # mouse_position is in the form [x,y], we only want the x part
            zy = mouse_position[1]

    pygame.display.flip()
```

As you can see, Pygame has a `mouse.get_pos()` function that actually gets the location of your mouse on the screen. This is simply an (x,y) coordinate.

Comment: thanx a lot. that was a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.MOUSEMOTION` events have a `rel` attribute (relative movement) which you can use to change the `x, y` coordinates. Just do `x += event.rel[0]` for the horizontal and `y += event.rel[1]` for the vertical movement.

You can also check if a mouse button is being pressed with `if event.buttons[0]:` (1 is the middle button and 2 is the right button).

To set the coords to the mouse position you can do this: `x, y = event.pos`.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
IMG = pg.Surface((120, 90))
IMG.fill((0, 120, 200))
x = 200
y = 300

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if event.buttons[0]:  # Left mouse button pressed.
                x += event.rel[0]
                y += event.rel[1]

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    screen.blit(IMG, (x, y))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```